# Flutter : How to delete Rest Api Using Http.Client?

Tags: api, codeigniter, flutter, dart

I develope App for CRUD Operation rest api using Http Client. **GET** and **POST** work perfectly, but problem come after **DELETE** Operation. 
Console Message show me response code **Bad Request 400 **, I Check code rest Api (in my codeigniter) **Bad Request 400** it's means the **ID** is null or not passing the ID on URL Rest Api.
[It's Console Message Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESB6o.png)

But I try on **POSTMAN** and **DELETE* is perfectly work , i dont know why in flutter http.delete not working. 
[It's Result POSTMAN Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbp8u.png)

My Api Url for Delete

```
http://192.168.43.159/wpu-rest-server/apii/mahasiswa/delete/
```

It's My **API.dart** :

```
Future<bool> checkPost(Map<String, dynamic> id) async {
    final client = http.Client();
    try {
      final response = await client.send(http.Request(
          "DELETE", Uri.parse("${Urls.BASE_API_URL}mahasiswa/delete/"))
        ..headers['Content-type']= 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        ..body = jsonEncode(id));
        print(response.reasonPhrase);
        print(response.statusCode.toString());
        print(response.request.toString());
        return response.statusCode == 204;
    } finally {}
  }
```

It's My **list.dart** :

```
void _checkPost() async{
    final post = {"id":widget.id};
    bool result = await api.checkPost(post);
     if (result) {
      _showSnackBar(
          context, 'Success ');
    } else {
      _showSnackBar(context, 'Failed');
      return null;
    }
  }
```

If you need Rest Api Code :

### Controller

```
public function delete_delete()
    {
        $id = $this->delete('id');
        $msgDelete = ['id' => $id, 'message' => 'Deleted the resource'];
        $msgEmpty = ['status' => false, 'message' => 'ID Not Found'];
        $msgBadRequest = ['status' => false, 'message' => 'Provide an ID'];

        if ($id === null) {
            $this->set_response($msgBadRequest, 400);
        } else {
            if ($this->mahasiswa->deleteMahasiswa($id) > 0) {
                $this->set_response($msgDelete, 204);
            } else {
                $this->set_response($msgEmpty, 404);
            }
        }
    }
```

### Model

```
public function deleteMahasiswa($id = null)
    {
        if ($id === null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            $this->db->delete('mahasiswa', ['id' => $id]);
            return $this->db->affected_rows();
        }
    }
```

I'm mistake something ?

> I ever heard httpclient.delete can't add **body** , but in **POSTMAN** need add body for deleting data, how to handle this ?

Comment: I did not see your code set header to "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". Could you try it? and tell me result.

Comment: @chunhunghan i try set header "Content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" , and nothing happen ,still get bad request message ,
i print console message header
`
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8, connection: close, x-powered-by: PHP/7.3.6, date: Fri, 09 Aug 2019 06:30:18 GMT, content-length: 42, server: Apache/2.4.39 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1c PHP/7.3.6
`